# the cmi.exit data model element

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

Suppose that the Activity Tree has two activities (Activity 1 and Activity 2). Activity 1's cmi.exit is set to empty characterstring by default and Activity 2's cmi.exit is set to "suspend" and "adl.nav.request" to "exitAll" and then Activity 2 calls Terminate(""). I want to know that whether the current information in the Run-Time Environment data model of Activity 2 is accessible in the next Sequencing Session or this data are discarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"exitAll" terminates the sequencing session without saving any data at all. So, the next sequencing session will start with fresh data. To be able to retrieve data in the next sequencing session, you need to call "suspendAll" instead. When "cmi.exit" is set to suspend, the current state of the suspended activity will be saved and will be available during the same sequencing session but it will not be available in the next sequening session unless you call "suspendAll".